# Can't use execl to list a specific directory

Tags: c, linux, shell, ls, os.execl

I am making a C program that lists files using `execl` to execute the `ls` command. If the program is called without any command line arguments, the current directory is listed and if the user specifies a file directory as a command line argument then that directory is listed.

`execl("/bin/ls", "ls", NULL);` works fine for listing the current directory

`execl(argv[1], "ls", NULL);` is what I'm using for the command line argument. I think this works fine code wise but I can't get the syntax right when I'm making the command line argument:

`./a.out /test/ls`

Comment: Is `./a.out /test/ls` supposed to list the files in the directory `/test/ls` ?

Comment: yup as in execl("/test/ls", "ls", NULL);

Answer (score 2):

Straight from the man page for `execl`

> The initial argument for these functions is the pathname of a file
>   which is to be executed.

So if the command you want to run is `ls`, then the first argument to `execl` should be `"/bin/ls"`.

The second argument to `execl` should also be `"/bin/ls"`.  This is due to the fact that the second argument to `execl` is passed as `argv[0]` to the program, and `argv[0]` is supposed to be the path to the program.

Thus, it's only starting at the third argument to `execl` that you actually start to pass real parameters to the command. So the call should look like this

```
execl( "/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", argv[1], NULL );
```

Comment: And, interestingly, if `argv[1]` is NULL (because no argument was passed), the result is still correct.  It would be trickier if you needed to pass more than one argument; at that point, `execv()` becomes the correct function.  Actually, I'd argue `execv()` is more often useful than `execl()`, but `execl()` is not useless for a fixed list of arguments.